# Redis: ERR command SLAVEOF is not allowed

Tags: redis

I'm trying to setup Redis replication in order to migrate data from server A to server B.  Server A is a master and on server B I'm running:

`SLAVEOF <A IP> <A PORT>`

But I get the error:

`ERR command SLAVEOF is not allowed`

Any idea what's causing this error?

Comment: Is server B operated by a Redis-as-a-Service provider? If not, which Redis version is it? Did you make any configuration changes to it?

Comment: @ItamarHaber Yes, server B is operated by RedisLabs and the Redis server version is 3.0.3.  No config changes that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redis Labs' Redis Cloud does not expose replication verbs to its users, as this is entirely managed by the service. You can refer to the [FAQ's answer about compatability with the open source comparison](https://redislabs.com/company/faqs?page_source=cloud#are-you-fully-compatible-with-open-source-redis) as well.

That said, **live migrations to our service via standard Redis replication are supported** - to achieve that simply contact our support team with your request for further assistance at https://redislabs.com/support